# TypeError 1009, began appearing randomly after adding new button code

Tags: actionscript-3

SOLVED: It was a two stop functions. Two. Stop. Functions. AS3 can be so annoying sometimes.

I am making a space invaders style game for a school assignment. I was adding in a button to go between frames and I deleted an unnecessary layer that contained a single sprite in my game, which I added back onto the main code layer. Then after attempting to restart my game to check the button, I began receiving a TypeError Code 1009. It is stating that there is an error with `MainTimeline/moveBullet()` and, `MainTimeline/eFrame()`. These sections of the code were not altered whatsoever during the creation of the button or movement of the sprite, however, as the bullet is linked to the moving sprite I think the error may be there. I'll put the code below, if anyone knows how to fix this specifically or has a general idea of how to do so please let me know. This is due in a few hours and would greatly appreciate a quick fix. Thanks.

Re-named sprites, re-typed code sections returning errors again. Most fixes appear to be in instance names, corrected them and no fix.

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame)

function eFrame(e: Event) {
        controls();
        restrain();
        moveBullet();
        enemyHit();
        barrierHit();

function moveBullet() {
            if (bull.visible == true) {
                bull.y -= bulletspeed;
                if (bull.y < 0) {
                    bull.visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

The game had been running fine until this point. The character would move along bottom and shoot up at "bad guys". Bullets were removing bad guys. Now I get the usual super fast run through frames repeatedly. NO Compiler Errors, just output, being

> TypeError: Error #1009

Answer (score 0):

> *"I deleted an unnecessary layer that contained a single sprite in my game, which I added back onto the main code layer. Then after attempting to restart my game to check the button, I began receiving a TypeError Code 1009."*

Possible solutions:

**(1)**

Did you also give the Sprite an **`instance`** name? I suspect the name `bull` is what's expected.

[image]

**(2)**

Eliminate that the problem is in `moveBullet()`. Disable the call and if the error still exists, then the problem must be between variables `bull` and `bulletspeed`.

Comment the call `movebullet()` in function `eFrame`:

```
function eFrame(e: Event) 
{
    //moveBullet();
    ....
```

Comment: The sprite I deleted was actually the user-controlled character (Ironman was the instance name). I had it on another layer as I was originally testing a different code which didn't work. I obviously just kept the sprite on that layer, made a whole new layer and did all the new code on that one. Then earlier today I noticed the layer was empty and deleted it, then I went and put another instance of the Ironman down with the same instance name. That's what confused me most as the error has nothing to do with what I got rid of. Thanks for your suggestion though, I appreciate your effort!